# Selecting text from multiple paragraphs using xpath

Tags: xpath

I have a situation where my end points and mid points can vary.

I always have:

```
<p style="margin-top: 0px;" >
```

and

```
<p class="contactAdvisor">
```

in between, I will have varying items including `<b>`, `<i>`, `<strong>`, `<br>` headings 1,2 or 3. I might also have one or more `<p>` in between the two fixed items.

What I'm trying to get is all of the text in between these two elements no matter whether wrapped in headings, various stylings or inside sub paragraph elements.

I've messed around with contains and preceding/following-sibling but my best attempt has been to create based on pre/follow for each use case. And even that leaves me with some issues because if there are multiple `<p>` inside and I'm trying to select all of them, I only get one.

Comment: Please provide a concrete sample XML/HTML and state the exact expected output given that particular sample.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hierarchy, you can use either preceding:: or preceding-sibling::.

Try selectong something along the lines of:

```
//*[preceding::p[@style="margin-top: 0px;"] and not (preceding::p[@class="contactAdvisor"])]
```

This should exclude everything before the first p with the first condition and everything after the second with the second. Untested so you may have to tweak the check a little.

Comment: Shouldn't the p[class= be p[@class=

Answer (score 0):

```
//p[@style="margin-top: 0px;"]/following::*[following::p[@class="contactAdvisor"]]

//*[preceding::p[@style="margin-top: 0px;"] and  following::p[@class="contactAdvisor"]]
```